# Optimizing reading/writing from csv to db in python

Tags: python

Let assume I have some table in DB created by downloading and reading CSV file (by line). CSV file updates sometimes.

csv has next structure (for example):

```
region;district
r1;d1
r1;d2
r2;d1
...
```

Also DB has two tables `region(id, title), district(id, region_id, title)`

At this moment my script does next things:
for EACH row in CSV-file:

1. select id from region where title=region
2. if the query is empty I insert new data and return the inserted `id`. else: just return `id`.
   (I need this id for `region_id` field of district table)

Here piece of code (bad code but maybe it can help):

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import csv

from aiopg.sa import create_engine
from io import TextIOWrapper
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, Column, Integer, String, Table
from zipfile import ZipFile

async def update_db():
    async with create_engine(user=DB_USER,
                             database=DB_NAME,
                             host=DB_HOST,
                             password=DB_PASSWORD) as engine:
        async with engine.acquire() as conn:
            with ZipFile(ZIP_FILENAME) as zip_file:
                with zip_file.open(CSV_FILENAME, 'r') as file:
                    metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)
                    _region, _district = get_db_tabels(metadata)
                    file = csv.reader(TextIOWrapper(file), delimiter=';')
                    headers = next(file)
                    for line in file:
                        region, district = line
                        result = await conn.execute(_region.select().where(_region.c.title==region))
                        if result.rowcount != 0:
                            for row in result:
                                region_id = row[0]
                                break;
                        else:
                            result = await conn.execute(_region.insert().values(title=region))
                            for row in result:
                                region_id = row[0]
                                break;
```

As I mentioned above, csv updates sometimes (and has huge size: million rows).
MAIN PROBLEM: How to detect new lines in csv? Can I check somehow if line (current region/district) already exists in db WITHOUT making queries for EACH line in csv?
RESTRICTIONS:

1. Lines do not append to file. (I can't save last row number somewhere)
2. I have no access to old csv file when download a new one (I can't compare to CSV files)
3. Use PostgreSQL, and all python libs mentioned in code.